# Increase database performance of COUNT(*) WHERE with Postgresql & Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application running SQLAlchemy and PostgresQL that handles massive amounts of data. One of the things we display on the front-end is a Dashboard with several aggregated stats for a given organization. Lately this endpoint had been running super slowly, so I've been trying to optimize it and increase performance.

I started by subclassing BaseQuery and implementing a leaner version of SQLAlchemy's built in `.count()` that counts without the use of a subquery.

**OptimisedQuery**

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import lazyload
from flask_sqlalchemy import BaseQuery

class OptimisedQuery(BaseQuery):
    def optimised_count(query):
        count_query = query.options(lazyload('*')).statement.with_only_columns([func.count()]).order_by(None)
        return query.session.execute(count_query).scalar()
```

**api/dashboard.py**

```
@dashboards.route("/api/dashboard/stats", methods=["GET"])
    @authentication_required
    def stats(current_user):
        org = current_user.organization

        total_subscribers = Subscriber.query.filter_by(
            unsubscribed=False, organization=org
        ).optimised_count()

        total_conversations = SubscriberConversationState.query.filter_by(
            organization=org
        ).optimised_count()

        total_messages = Message.query.filter_by(
            organization=org
        ).optimised_count()

        total_unsubscribers = Subscriber.query.filter_by(
            unsubscribed=True, organization=org
        ).optimised_count()

        return jsonify(
            dict(
                total_subscribers=total_subscribers,
                total_conversations=total_conversations,
                total_messages=total_messages,
                total_unsubscribers=total_unsubscribers,
            )
        )
```

*This was definitely a step in the right direction*, reducing the endpoint latency significantly. That being said, it was still taking from 9-15 seconds to load, so I dove into New Relic and saw that one of the queries (count on the messages table) was still performing really badly. The below screenshot was actually the BEST I could find at ~1.5s, but sometimes it takes up to 6s.

[image: New Relic Trace]

This is not *that* surprising, since the messages table is the largest of the bunch (4,090,065 rows). However, looking at the query, it seemed about as lean as could possibly be, even if I was to ditch SQLAlchemy and just write pure SQL. What's even stranger is that after cloning the prod db to my local machine and  profiling the same query using `pgbench`, the query ran lightning fast, with an average latency of 86.9ms.

[image: pgbench]

## Questions

- Is the final reduced query, `SELECT count(*) AS count_1 FROM message WHERE %(param_1)s = messages.organization_id`, the leanest the query can get?
- I've found tons of articles addressing `COUNT` performance and strategies for increasing it, but none for `COUNT WHERE` queries. Are
  there things I can do in my database construction to speed it up in
  this case? (Indexes, etc.)
- What might be causing the difference between `pgbench` 86.9ms of latency and the production runtimes of over 6s? For reference, the
  app is hosted on Heroku and leverages 3 Standard-2X web dynos and a
  Postgres Standard-0 add-on.

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts: If your production environment is serving requests from many different users and your local environment is only processing requests from you then that could make a significant difference. Also, if your pgbench test is running the same query 50 times in a row then the first iteration could be rather slow and the next 49 much faster (due to caching) so the average of those 50 iterations could be heavily biased downward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pgbench run keeps asking for the same `organization_id` repeatedly, so the data are probably cached. Besides, there might be organizations with more messages. So I am not surprised that the runtimes are different.

Since you have already read up on [the performance of `count(*)`](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/), I'll spare you the details. I see two options:

1. Use a materialized view that you refresh regularly:

   ```
   CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW message_count AS
   SELECT organization_id, count(*) AS c
   FROM messages
   GROUP BY organization_id;

   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON message_count (organization_id);
   ```

   Then you'll have slightly stale data, but you will be fast.
2. If you need exact counts, make `message_count` a regular table and add triggers to `messages` that update the appropriate `message_count` row whenever `messages` is modified.

   That will slow down data modifications on `messages`, but if you really need that count frequently and fast, it might be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.The materialized view suggestion looks really cool. I’ll have to try that.